# Why useFetch is not working on page change in nuxt3 on client side?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I just started learning nuxtjs (have some experience in vue.js) and I stuck into the following problem:

I have a simple `todo-[id].vue` page. It should get an todo from the API and render on the page:

```html
<script setup>
import Section from '~~/components/UI/containers/section.vue';
import ButtonLink from '~~/components/UI/buttons/button-link.vue';

const route = useRoute()
const todoId = parseInt(route.params.id)
const { data: todo } = await useFetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todoId}`)
</script>

<template>
  <Section>
    <div class="mt-4 flex space-x-4">
      <ButtonLink :to="{name: 'todo-id', params: {id: todoId - 1}}" type="secondary" v-show="todoId !== 1">previous</ButtonLink>
      <ButtonLink :to="{name: 'todo-id', params: {id: todoId + 1}}">next</ButtonLink>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-6">
      <p class="text-lg" :class="[todo.completed ? 'text-green-600' : 'text-red-600']">{{ todo.title }} (#{{ todo.id }})</p>
    </div>
  </Section>
</template>
```

It works fine on the server side, but when I'm clicking on the `next` button it does not call the API to get next item, page's url is changing. What should I do to call the API on the client side? As I remember it works fine in vue.js

Comment: What is `button-link`? Also, where is the code of your snippet located? In `todo-[id].vue` too? What do you see in your console/network tab?

Comment: hey.. se my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415150/nuxt-3-problem-with-wildcard-pages-and-usefetch/73453666#73453666 . just use $fetch() instead of useFetch.

Answer (score 7):

`useFetch` tries to cache the document for you and reuses the cache when you load the next page. To avoid that behavior you can pass a function instead of a string:

```js
useFetch(() => `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todoId}`)
```

or provider your own key:

```js
useFetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todoId}`, { key: `todo:${todoId}` })
```

Docu: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch

Comment: I had the same issue as OP. This worked!

Answer (score 3):

From [nuxt3's useFetch documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch/#params):

> watch: watch reactive sources to auto-refresh.

Also, I currently have to set `key` and `initialCache: false` to useFetch to make sure the fetch run every time enter page.

Comment: This does not work for me. Could you show an example of yours?
I tried to generate a key with a timecode (so I get something new) and I have set initialCache to false. Also the refetch should anyway happen because the URL changes...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using Nuxt 3 i added:

```
server: false
```

> useFetc:h Source Fetch data from an API endpoint with a SSR-friendly
> composable.

By default, useFetch fetches the data on the server.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch