# Nuxt 3: Problem with wildcard pages and useFetch

Tags: nuxtjs3

I have a problem with a wildcard page `/pages/[...slug].vue` and fetching from backend.

I have a computed called `url` that I use in:

```
const { data, refresh } = await useFetch(url.value)
```

Then I have a watcher to refresh the useFetch:

```
watch(url, (url, oldUrl) => {
  console.log(url)
  console.log(oldUrl)
  refresh()
})
```

In the browser, the console log shows the correct url, but useFetch just loaded the old url again.

Any idea what's wrong here? Thanks.

[edit: clarification: this is when navigation in browser, that triggers the watch]

Comment: Did you try any another browser?  I had the problem in safari and I changed to Firefox..

Comment: Tried chrome and safari, same result

Comment: ok, What happaned If you put url in borwser bar?

Answer (score 0):

I believe because computed is a 'getter' behind the scenes you need to use a deep watcher on it or watch the returned value directly otherwise the watch function will not run.

You could change your watch function to to:

```
watch(url, (url, oldUrl) => {
  console.log(url)
  console.log(oldUrl)
  refresh()
},
{ deep: true }
)
```

Alternatively you could directly watch the value of the computed property:

```
watch( () => url.value, (url, oldUrl) => {
  console.log(url)
  console.log(oldUrl)
  refresh()
},
{ deep: true }
)
```

There is a bit more information here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same issue 2 days ago.. i guess that the issue happens because of the default keep alive props and internal caching.

My solution was to use `$fetch()` instead of `useFetch()`.

Like that you also don't need the watcher anymore.